# How can I change Excel 2010 date format display?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am working on a global financial app that uses Excel for the UI. The dates should be displayed in the appropriate format for each language & culture. For some columns I am able to change the date format but not for others. How can I change Excel 2010 date format display?
[image: Date Format is not changed]

Comment: As the `(*)` in the screen-cap says, `*` formats are dependent on system settings, e.g. what you set in the Windows regional settings control panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the format for some dates that may mean those dates are formatted as text.

Test by using `ISNUMBER` function, e.g. `=ISNUMBER(A1)` - FALSE indicates those dates are formatted as text.

If that's the case you can convert a whole column to true dates by using **Text to Columns** functionality.

Select a single column > Data > Text to columns > Next > Next > under "column data format" choose "Date" and from the dropdown choose the appropriate format based on the source, e.g. if dates look like 2012-12-25 then that's YMD > OK > ESC

Now format dates using one of the * formats so that they change according to regional settings as Marc B says

Comment: Yep, changing the "column data format" resolved the issue. Thanks, Barry.

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional `Local:=True` when opening the file programmatically. This ensures that any number stored as a serial date will be formatted per the user's system locale.

```
Sub OpenFileLocalDateSettings()
Dim wbFullName as String
Dim wb as Workbook
wbFullName = "C:\The File You Want To Open.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wbFullName, Local:=True)
' execute more code below this line
'
'
'
End SUb
```